# Background activity launch blocked when device runs Android 14

Tags: android, android-intent, media, android-auto, android-media3

I have an Android app in the store, and it's working well on Android 13 and below, however there are some issues related to Android 14.   The app is a media streaming app, with Android Auto support.   The app has a MediaLibraryService that launches an activity on the device when the user is interacting via Android Auto library.

This all worked on Android 13, however on Android 14, Android Auto just sits there with "getting your selection" displayed on the head unit.

I have done some digging, and usually this calls the override for onAddMediaItems, which in turn launches the activity intent, if the application isn't running.

I have seen the Android 14 documentation, and modified my code as follows, however I still get the following in the log:

`10-13 18:26:29.705  1000  1519  5569 W ActivityTaskManager: Background activity launch blocked [callingPackage: uk.dev.myapp; callingUid: 10384; appSwitchState: 2; callingUidHasAnyVisibleWindow: false; callingUidProcState: BOUND_TOP; isCallingUidPersistentSystemProcess: false; balAllowedByPiSender: BackgroundStartPrivileges[allowsBackgroundActivityStarts=true, allowsBackgroundForegroundServiceStarts=true, originatingToken=null]; realCallingPackage: uk.dev.myapp; realCallingUid: 10384; realCallingUidHasAnyVisibleWindow: false; realCallingUidProcState: BOUND_TOP; isRealCallingUidPersistentSystemProcess: false; originatingPendingIntent: PendingIntentRecord{1f928a5 uk.dev.myapp startActivity}; backgroundStartPrivileges: BackgroundStartPrivileges[allowsBackgroundActivityStarts=false, allowsBackgroundForegroundServiceStarts=false, originatingToken=null]; intent: Intent { act=uk.dev.myapp.TaskerIntentReceiver.PLAY_STREAM flg=0x10000000 pkg=uk.dev.myapp cmp=uk.dev.myapp/.StreamListMainActivity (has extras) }; callerApp: ProcessRecord{632cf06 19377:uk.dev.myapp/u0a384}; inVisibleTask: false]`

My code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent( this, StreamListMainActivity.class );
                intent.setAction( StreamListMainActivity.PLAY_STREAM );
                intent.putExtra( StreamListMainActivity.STREAM_INDEX, Index );
                intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
                intent.setPackage( getContext().getPackageName() );
                ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeBasic();
                options.setPendingIntentBackgroundActivityStartMode( ActivityOptions.MODE_BACKGROUND_ACTIVITY_START_ALLOWED );
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( context, 998, intent, FLAG_IMMUTABLE, options.toBundle() );
                try
                {
                    pendingIntent.send();
                }
                catch ( PendingIntent.CanceledException e )
                {
                    AppLogger.Exception( LOG_TAG, e );
                }
```

My service is defined like so:

```
        <service
            android:name=".AudioPlayerService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:ignore="MissingIntentFilterForMediaSearch"
            android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="androidx.media3.session.MediaLibraryService" />
                <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Followed the guidance here:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-14#java

and expected the app to launch when user selects media from the Android Auto head unit.

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting the documentation about the background starts restriction. Your background `Service` is trying to launch an `Activity`. This is only permitted under certain situations. Setting the flag `ActivityOptions.MODE_BACKGROUND_ACTIVITY_START_ALLOWED` yourself isn't going to work around this situation, that flag needs to be set in the `PendingIntent` that triggered your `Service`. How does your `Service` get triggered to launch the `Activity` you want to launch?

Comment: Android Auto would have called it.   The easiest way to reproduce the issue is to Force Stop my app, and then connect to Android Auto, which starts the media service, which in turn needs to launch an activity within my app.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidWasser, your comment has clarified the documentation, and lead me to change my app so it doesn't need to launch the app on the phone, everything in the service is now self-contained to support Android Auto.  It doesn't fix the original issue, however I suspect my implementation was less than ideal previously, and now it's working the way it's supposed to work.

Comment: Glad you were able to fix it. You might want to create an answer explaining how you resolved it, in case anyone else has a similar problem.